# How to get the running time in the Pylint of each file

Tags: django, pylint, pylintrc

I am using the pylint in my project and it runs over 1min which is too long for me .How can I get the specific running time of each file in my project?

Here is my research:

[The issue on the github](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1416)

[How to speed up pylint](http://grokbase.com/t/python/code-quality/14cppcjfev/speeding-up-pylint)

Can you give me some advice about the issue and how to speed up the pylint ?

thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

I create a new checker class and add the print sentences to get the time. I think it is not the best way and I will do the further research

```
from pylint.checkers import BaseChecker
from pylint.interfaces import IAstroidChecker


class CustomTimeChecker(BaseChecker):
    """
    find the check type in the following url:
    https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/63eb8c4663a77d0caf2a842b716e4161f9763a16/pylint/checkers/typecheck.py
    """
    print(begin)
    __implements__ = IAstroidChecker
    name = 'import-time-checker'
    priority = -1

    def __init__(self, linter):
        super().__init__(linter)
        print('test In samuel !')

    def visit_importfrom(self, node):
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
         print('')

    def visit_import(self, node):
)

    def visit_attribute(self, node):
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('        function Name  '+str(node.name)+ ' takes the time for '+ str(end - self.begin))

    def leave_functiondef(self, node):
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('        function Name  '+str(node.name)+ ' takes the time for '+ str(end - self.begin))

    def leave_module(self, node):
        """
        Actual checks are implemented here
        """
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('Leaving the module ' + str(node.name) +' when the time is '+str(end - self.begin))
        print('*'*40)
        # print(node.name)

    def visit_module(self, node):
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('Entering the module ' + str(node.name) + ' when the time is' + str(end - self.begin))


def register(linter):
    linter.register_checker(CustomTimeChecker(linter))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up `pylint` by spawning multiple processes and [checking files in parallel](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#parallel-execution). This functionality is exposed via the `-j` command-line parameter. If the provided number is `0`, then the total number of CPUs will be autodetected and used. From the output of `pylint --help`:

```
-j <n-processes>, --jobs=<n-processes>
    Use multiple processes to speed up Pylint. Specifying
    0 will auto-detect the number of processors available
    to use. [current: 1]
```

There are some limitations in running checks in parallel in the current implementation. It is not possible to use custom plugins (i.e. `--load-plugins` option), nor it is not possible to use initialization hooks (i.e. the `--init-hook` option).